# Deleting File Path extension don't work, when we have to convert video format from .MOV to .MP4

Tags: ios, objective-c, avasset, phasset

As i select a video from Gallery i am getting selected file extension as .MOV so wanted to convert it to .MP4 researched but not getting how to do that in this case. If u have any idea please help.

```
  - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
 {


selectedVideoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
if( [picker sourceType] == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera )
{
    NSURL *videoURL=info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];
    [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:videoURL completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error )
     {
         //here is your URL : assetURL
         NSLog(@"url is%@",assetURL);

         PHFetchResult<PHAsset*> *assets = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[assetURL]
                                                                       options:nil];


         PHAsset *asset1 = assets.firstObject;
         [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:asset1 options:nil resultHandler:^(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
             if ([asset isKindOfClass:[AVURLAsset class]]) {
                 AVURLAsset* urlAsset = (AVURLAsset*)asset;
                 NSNumber *size;

                 [urlAsset.URL getResourceValue:&size forKey:NSURLFileSizeKey error:nil];
                 NSLog(@"size video of camera %f",[size floatValue]/(1024.0*1024.0)); //size is 43.703005
                 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlAsset.URL];
                 NSLog(@"length of camera %f",[data length]/(1024.0*1024.0)); // data size is 43.703005

                 sizeofVideo=[size floatValue]/(1024.0*1024.0);

                 NSLog(@"sizeofVideo arvin %f",sizeofVideo);
                 if (!sizeofVideo>50.00) {
                     selectedVideoURL=nil;
                     UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"size of video exist 50MB" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                     [alert show];

                     attachnoteLbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Attach Note:0"];
                 }
                  attachnoteLbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Attach Note:1"];

             }
         }];
     }];
}

else

{
    NSURL *videoURL=info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    NSLog(@" valid is%@",[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]);
    //else this is valid : [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]];
    PHFetchResult<PHAsset*> *assets = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[videoURL]
                                                                  options:nil];


    PHAsset *asset1 = assets.firstObject;


     AVURLAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoURL options:nil];
    NSArray *compatiblePresets = [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:avAsset];

    // Check if video is supported for conversion or not
    if ([compatiblePresets containsObject:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality])
    {
        //Create Export session
        AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession       alloc]initWithAsset:avAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality];

        //Creating temp path to save the converted video
        NSString* documentsDirectory=     [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* myDocumentPath= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp.mp4"];
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:myDocumentPath];

        NSData* data = [myDocumentPath dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        //Check if the file already exists then remove the previous file
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:myDocumentPath])
        {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtPath:myDocumentPath error:nil];
        }
        exportSession.outputURL = url;
        //set the output file format if you want to make it in other file format (ex .3gp)
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
        exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

        [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
            switch ([exportSession status])
            {
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                    NSLog(@"Export session failed");
                    break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                    NSLog(@"Export canceled");
                    break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                {
                    //Video conversion finished
                    NSLog(@"Successful!");
                }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Video file not supported!");
    }

    [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:asset1 options:nil resultHandler:^(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
        if ([asset isKindOfClass:[AVURLAsset class]]) {
            AVURLAsset* urlAsset = (AVURLAsset*)asset;
            NSNumber *size;

            [urlAsset.URL getResourceValue:&size forKey:NSURLFileSizeKey error:nil];
            NSLog(@"size video of phassetis %f",[size floatValue]/(1024.0*1024.0)); //size is 43.703005
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlAsset.URL];
            NSLog(@"length %f",[data length]/(1024.0*1024.0)); // data size is 43.703005
            sizeofVideo=[size floatValue]/(1024.0*1024.0);

            NSLog(@"sizeofVideo arvin %f",sizeofVideo);
            if (sizeofVideo>50.00) {
                selectedVideoURL=nil;
                UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"size of video exist 50MB" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
                 attachnoteLbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Attach Note:0"];

            }
             attachnoteLbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Attach Note:1"];

        }
    }];

}

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
_importView.hidden=YES;

 }
```

I have tried the following way by deleting the file extension from.MOV to .MP4 while uploading it but din't worked.So i think need to convert it in the begging only while selecting it from gallery or camera.But not getting how to do that.Any help is appreciated

```
-(void)afnetworking{

 NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myDocumentPath];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
if(data)

{

    //     NSString *videoName = [[videoUrl lastPathComponent]stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSData *videoData  = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
    [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSString *tmpfileinfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video_clip\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",videoData];
    [bodyData appendData:[tmpfileinfo dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:[NSData dataWithData:videoData]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all you have to select video from photogallery, which you are already doing.

2) After that you have to export selected video to document directory.

3) Then you have to select video from document directory path while you are uploading to server.

```
 // Create the asset url with the video file
        AVURLAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoURL options:nil];
        NSArray *compatiblePresets = [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:avAsset];

        // Check if video is supported for conversion or not
        if ([compatiblePresets containsObject:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality])
        {
        //Create Export session
             AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession       alloc]initWithAsset:avAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality];

        //Creating temp path to save the converted video
             NSString* documentsDirectory=     [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
             NSString* myDocumentPath= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp.mp4"];
             NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:myDocumentPath];

        //Check if the file already exists then remove the previous file
             if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:myDocumentPath])
             {
                  [[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtPath:myDocumentPath error:nil];
             }
             exportSession.outputURL = url;
             //set the output file format if you want to make it in other file format (ex .3gp)
             exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
             exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

             [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
             switch ([exportSession status])
             {
                  case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                       NSLog(@"Export session failed");
                       break;
                  case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                       NSLog(@"Export canceled");
                       break;
                  case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                  {
                       //Video conversion finished
                       NSLog(@"Successful!");
                  }
                       break;
                  default:
                       break;
              }
             }];
        }
        else
        {
               NSLog(@"Video file not supported!");
        }
```

**EDIT**

```
-(void)afnetworking{
NSUrl *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myDocumentPath];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
   if(data)
{
    NSString *videoName = [[videoUrl lastPathComponent]stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSData *videoData  = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:selectedVideoURL];
    [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSString *tmpfileinfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video_clip\"; filename=\"%@.mp4\"\r\n",videoName];
    [bodyData appendData:[tmpfileinfo dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:[NSData dataWithData:videoData]];

}
```

Comment: what we are doing gat the line NSString* myDocumentPath= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp.mp4"];  we don't want to add temp.mp4 we just want filename.mp4  can you explain it to me.

Comment: @vicky that line is for output video path, you can give what ever name you want. We are storing video inside Document directory.

Comment: means it is just for storing purpose original file name (the file we are picking up from gallery) does't change ? right. @Bhadresh Mulsaniya

Comment: @vicky yes bro. It's just naming convention. File you are picking from gallery has system name assigned.

Comment: dude but i am getting problem in using myDocumentPath in the below method -(void )afnetworking in this method i am using myDocumentPath at selectedVideoUrl but it's giving me error any help

Comment: NSUrl *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myDocumentPath];    at this line it is saying use of undeclared identifier myDocumentPath

Comment: NSString* myDocumentPath; declare it Globally.

Comment: [NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'     at this line in afnetworking  it crashes here

Comment: Where you have write my code? check myDocumentPath value/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116857/discussion-between-vicky-and-bhadresh-mulsaniya).